# jQuery myClass.click not working but html.click function is working

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

for the life of me I can't figure this out. I've tried classes, IDs and regular element selectors. Below is a snippet I'm trying to run.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".myClass").click(function () {
        console.log("Hello!");
    });
});
```

The example above will NOT run. However when changing it to the example below it will run.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("html").click(function () {
        console.log("Hello!");
    });
});
```

Example HTML below

```
<div class="mapLegend">
<div class="mapLegend-header">
    <h2>Map Key</h2>
    <a href="" class="myClass">
        <img class="mapLegend-expandCollapse icon-sm" src="/app/img/Forward-Arrow-64.png" />
    </a>
</div>
<div class="mapLegend-content">
    <div class="mapLegend-value">
        <img alt="" src="/app/img/freight-map/last_truck_location.png" />
        <span class="label">Last Truck Location</span">
    </div>
    <div class="mapLegend-value">
        <img alt="" src="/app/img/Drop_hollow.png" />
        <span class="label">Delivered Load</span>
    </div>
    <div class="mapLegend-value">
        <img alt="" src="/app/img/freight-map/first_pick.png" />
        <span class="label">First Pick</span>
    </div>
    <div class="mapLegend-value">
        <div class="dot addPick"></div>
        <span class="label">Additional Pick</span>
    </div>
    <div class="mapLegend-value">
        <div class="dot checkCall"></div>
        <span class="label">Check Call / Previous Location</span>
    </div>
    <div class="mapLegend-value">
        <div class="dot addDrop"></div>
        <span class="label">Additional Drop</span>
    </div>
    <div class="mapLegend-value">
        <img alt="" src="/app/img/freight-map/final_stop.png" />
        <span class="label">Final Drop</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

It seems as if anytime I try to tie my function to a class or ID it doesn't want to run. I have also tried the .on("click", function()) method as well with the same results.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I've never ran into this before.

Thanks!

Comment: share the html code

Comment: Impossible to answer without seeing the html. It's possible your "myclass" element is under something else that is blocking the click? What's the html?

Comment: I've updated my question to show the example HTML. I have updated the class to multiple different classes to see if it was a nesting issue. Also when I reference ("html").click it is just basically firing whenever I click anywhere on the html.

Comment: Are you dynamically generating the elements that you are trying to bind the event handler to?

Comment: which class you're refering to ?

Comment: In your  HTML, there is no element with class `myClass` so that you can click on that.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, that was my mistake when I was copying the code over to here. I've been trying a few different names/selectors and it wasn't updated prior to pasting here. I've updated my code so it should all be the same now. I basically changed <a id="loganTest"> to <a class="myClass">

Comment: I got your example to work no problem. I passed in the event to the click handler function and called preventDefault on it.
https://jsfiddle.net/8jfxuydz/4/

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/734363/)? Note you do have a type-o of a double quote in one of your span elements `<span class="label">Last Truck Location</span">` When I fixed that it worked in the fiddle i created.

Answer (score -1):

Your code runs, but cause is `<a> element`, it refresh all the page and as result you don't see the console.log. If you really want to add click event on `<a>`, you should add the following line.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".myClass").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("clicked");
    });
});
```

The variable `e`and the function `preventDefault()` is the key here. As you can guess the preventDefault doesn't run the default code for `<a>` so it will not refresh your page.

I hope to help you a bit